# Maximum likelihood estimation using a random number generator

Tags: st.statistics

Imagine that I have a random number generator $X$ where it is impossible (or mathematicaly intractable) to calculate its probability density function.

That random variable depends of one (or more) parameters $\alpha$ that I want to ajust in order to maximize a likelihood function $L$ (for a given a set of observations $x_1, ..., x_n$)

My question is how can I find the parameters $\alpha$ that maximize the likelihood function using just the random number generator.

Comment: Consider X which selects digits from alpha's base-2 representation, which will probably make the problem intractable.  I think you'll want some assumptions on the pdf.

Comment: Have you searched for Metropolis-Hasting algorithm in case that meets your demand?